# can't convert from delpi to C#

Tags: c#, delphi

Hi I am trying to write a plugin for Delphi application in C# I am exporting my functions using UnmanagedExports library (first lib on NuGet)

but now I have a problem converting example plugin code which is written in Delpi to C#

```
library myplugin;

uses
    SysUtils,
    Classes,
    Dialogs;

type
    P_RDSGroup=^TRDSGroup;
    TRDSGroup = record
        Year: word;
        Month: byte;
        Day: byte;
        Hour: byte;
        Minute: byte;
        Second: byte;
        Centisecond: byte;
        RFU: word;
        Blk1: integer;
        Blk2: integer;
        Blk3: integer;
        Blk4: integer;
end;

var
    PI: integer;
    Group: TRDSGroup;

{$R *.res}

procedure RDSGroup(PRDSGroup: P_RDSGroup); stdcall;
    begin
    Group:=PRDSGroup^;
    if (Group.Blk1>=0) then
        begin
    if (PI<>Group.Blk1) then
    begin
    PI:=Group.Blk1;
    ShowMessage('New PI has been detected: '+IntToHex(PI,4));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure Command(Cmd, Param: PChar); stdcall;
    var w: string;
    begin
    w:=UpperCase(string(Cmd));
    if (w='CONFIGURE') then
        ShowMessage('Nothing to configure in this simple plugin.');
    if (w='RESETDATA') then PI:=-1;
    end;

function PluginName: PChar; stdcall;
begin
    Result:='My First Plugin';
end;

Exports
    RDSGroup, Command, PluginName;

begin
PI:=-1;
end
```

and I am trying to translate it in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace MyFirstRDSSpy_Plugin
{

    public class Class1
    {


        //P_RDSGroup = TRDSGroup; //Don't know what =^ does
        public struct TRDSGroup
        {
            public ushort Year;
            public byte Month;
            public byte Day;
            public byte Hour;
            public byte Minutes;
            public byte Second;
            public byte Centisecond;
            public ushort RFU;
            public int Blk1;
            public int Blk2;
            public int Blk3;
            public int Blk4;

        }
        static int PI; 
        static TRDSGroup Group;

        static void RDSGroup(TRDSGroup *PRDSGroup);
        {
            Group = *PRDSGroup; //not sure if fixed right?
            if (Group.Blk1 >= 0)
                {
                if (PI != Group.Blk1) {
                    PI = Group.Blk1;
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New PI has been detected:" + PI.ToString("X4"));
                }
            }

         }
    static void Command(string Cmd, string Param)
    {
        var w = "";
        w = Cmd.ToUpper();
        if (w == "CONFIGURE")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Nothing to configure in this simple plugin.");

        }
        if (w == "RESETDATA")
        {
            PI = -1;
        }
    }
    static void PluginName()
    {
        return "My First Plugin";
    }
    //EXPORTS GO HERE
    [DllExport("RDSGroup", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [DllExport("Command", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [DllExport("PluginName", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    //EXPORTS GO HERE
}
}
```

But it will not compile
1. I need to show message box but I don't know how can I do that from Class Library in C#
2. I need to do P_RDSGroup=^TRDSGroup; but I don't know how to do this in C#
3. not sure how to translate PChar (I think its Char but I not sure)

for anyone wondering plugin docs for application I want to write plugin for are here: http://rdsspy.com/download/pdf/spyapi.pdf

Hope someone can help me here
Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: In delphi, a `word` is equivalent to a C# `ushort`, not a `string`.

Comment: By the way, there is a lot in here that isn't valid C# code (which is why it won't compile), for example I'm not sure what the intent here was: `static void RDSGroup(PRDSGroup: P_RDSGroup)`? Looks like you are doing a copy/paste of some Delphi code in C# and that just won't work.

Comment: I am trying to convert Delpi procedure RDSGroup and since its procedure it won't return anything which is equvalent to void in C# I Think
also there is some stuff like P_RDSGroup=^TRDSGroup which I am not sure what its C# exuivalent  for =^ is 

not realy sure what I must put for its parameters because PRDSGroup: P_RDSGroup is not a string nor int so I am not sure what to do here

Comment: He means the syntax of the parameter. `PRDSGroup: P_RDSGroup` is how it would be done in Delphi, but is not valid in C#.

Comment: `P_RDSGroup=^TRDSGroup;` in Delphi means *`P_RDSGroup` is a pointer to `TRDSGroup`*. So if you were talking about C (not C#), the equivalent method signature would be: `void RDSGroup(TRDSGroup *PRDSGroup);`

Comment: How can you attempt this task if you don't know basic delphi syntax? People have such unrealistic expectations.

Comment: @David: I have translated and even modified Python and Ruby code without knowing the (full) basic syntax, but I was able to find out what the syntax used meant exactly and to amend or translate the code I needed (e.g. Jekyll -- Ruby -- or Pygments -- Python). Took some time learning that part of the languages I needed to know. I assume PersonalNonGrata could do the same. <g>

Comment: FWIW, there is no =^ operator in Delphi. It is `PA = ^TA`, which means that PA is a pointer (^) to a TA.

Comment: @David
I am doing it by googling a bit and as its a small piece of code I said why not try it

just didn't know what = ^ meant, Now I know thats a pointer, which means something like this: static unsafe TRDSGroup *P_RDSGroup should work

Comment: @Persona: No, that should not work. AFAIK, there are no typedefs in C#. Your `static unsafe TRDSGroup *P_RDSGroup` declares a *variable* of type `TRDSGroup *`, not a type. But Pascal `type P_RDSGroup = ^TRDSGroup` *does* declare a type.

Comment: @Persona: So `procedure RDSGroup(PRDSGroup: P_RDSGroup); stdcall;` should be converted as `static void RDSGroup(TRDSGroup *PRDSGroup);`. You can not define the pointer type `P_RDSGroup`, so you'll have to spell it out as `TRDSGroup *` each time it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that helped I was finaly able to fix it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace MyFirstRDSSpy_Plugin
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static unsafe TRDSGroup* P_RDSGroup;
    public struct TRDSGroup
{
        public ushort Year;
        public byte Month;
        public byte Day;
        public byte Hour;
        public byte Minutes;
        public byte Second;
        public byte Centisecond;
        public ushort RFU;
        public int Blk1;
        public int Blk2;
        public int Blk3;
        public int Blk4;

    }
    static int PI;
    static TRDSGroup Group;

    [DllExport("RDSGroup", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe static void RDSGroup(TRDSGroup* PRDSGroup)
    {
        Group = *PRDSGroup;
        if (Group.Blk1 >= 0)
        {
            if (PI != Group.Blk1) {
                PI = Group.Blk1;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New PI has been detected:" + PI.ToString("X4"));
            }
        }

    }
    [DllExport("Command", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static void Command(string Cmd, string Param)
    {
        var w = "";
        w = Cmd.ToUpper();
        if (w == "CONFIGURE")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Nothing to configure in this simple plugin.");

        }
        if (w == "RESETDATA")
        {
            PI = -1;
        }
    }
    [DllExport("PluginName", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static string PluginName()
        {
        return "My First Plugin";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use WinForms just add it as a Reference (System.Windows.Forms)